# no se llena la lista cuando se genera la pantalla, pero al dar hot reload ya la carga, algo mal con el async - awa

Tags: flutter, async-await, singleton

### Carga lista de forma asincrona

Aprendiendo desarrollo con flutter: no se carga la lista al construir la pantalla, pero si lo hace si doy hot reload, supongo es un problema de asincronía.

Quisiera saber como hacer para que se cargue al construirse la pantalla.

Intento utilizar un singleton para reutilizar la lista en varias pantallas sin necesidad de leer el archivo o la api.

```
//--- main.dart ----

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './screens/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:clean_arch/services/provincia_service.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ProvinciaService();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => const HomeScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}


//--- home_screen.dart'; ---------

import 'package:clean_arch/services/provincia_service.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ProvinciaService.provincias.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                            ProvinciaService.provincias[index].toString())),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tienes la idea. Prueba colocando esa llamada en un bloc (veo que tiene `package:clean_arch/`) y prueba con un BlocBuilder o en otro caso utiliza un FutureBuilder si mi primera opción no es acertada. Cualquier cosa provee más información y con mucho gusto.

Comment: Puedes por favor colocar el código de tu `ProvinciaService`. De esta forma es más sencillo ayudarte. Quedo pendiente. Saludos

Comment: Intente replicar tu código así con esa clase estática de `ProvinciaService` y me funciona perfectamente. Podrías compartir el código de esa clase?

Comment: `import 'provincia.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class ProvinciaService {
  static List<Provincia> provincias = [];

  static final ProvinciaService _instance = ProvinciaService._();
  ProvinciaService._() {
    _readProvinciasFromJson();
  }
  factory ProvinciaService() => _instance;

  _readProvinciasFromJson() async {
    String str =
        await File('C:/FLUTTER/DART/clean/lib/provi.json').readAsString();

    List<Provincia> lst = List<Provincia>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((p) => Provincia.fromJson(p)));

    provincias.addAll(lst);
  }}`

Comment: @BrProgrammer ahi subi la clase ProvinciaService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambie tu code un poco. Al no usar un gestor de estado. Como intermediario entre vista y service (Que es el deber ser). Lo que hice fue usar un `ValueNotifier` en lugar de la lista.
El code queda de la siguiente manera. Ignora el `TestPage`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'provincia.dart';


class ProvinciaService {
  factory ProvinciaService() => _instance;
  ProvinciaService._() {
    _readProvinciasFromJson();
  }

  static final ValueNotifier<List<Provincia>> provinces =
      ValueNotifier<List<Provincia>>([]);
  static final ProvinciaService _instance = ProvinciaService._();
  Future<void> _readProvinciasFromJson() async {
    final str =
        await File('C:/FLUTTER/DART/clean/lib/provi.json').readAsString();

    final lst = List<Provincia>.from(
      (json.decode(str) as List).map(
        (j) => Provincia.fromJson(j as Map<String, dynamic>),
      ),
    );
    provinces.value = [...provinces.value, ...lst];
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<List<Provincia>>(
      valueListenable: ProvinciaService.provinces,
      builder: (_, provinces, __) => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: provinces.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) => Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(provinces.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, es un problema de sincronía, tú estás detonando tu método en el constructor en el método main. Entonces lo más probable es que no existe datos hasta el momento que se muestra el primer frame de la pantalla. Tienes dos soluciones.
La fácil.
Refactorizar y llamar tu servicio dentro de la vista, para esto usas el widget Future Builder
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html
La compleja, a mi parecer si estás iniciando:
Utilizar un gestor de estados para que dentro de la lógica se notifique a la vista que debe actualizar la misma y se mostrará el resultado, puedes usar lo que te parezca más fácil: provider, bloc, incluso set state, pero no es una buena práctica, ya que se puede hacer de esa manera.